# Safari for Ipad not reporting line numbers on Javascript errors

Tags: javascript, ipad, safari

I am using iPad 2 with IOs 5 to develop a web application.

I have enabled the developer console to get logs , but when javascript error occurs it does not include corresponding line number.

*Since the web application handles touch and gesture events, I cannot test them on desktop version of the browser!*

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: the web application handles touch and gesture events, I cannot test them on desktop version of the browser

Comment: I'm still seeing this issue.  So infuriatingly simple it's criminal to not post file and line.

Comment: Note that iOS 6 (if you choose to upgrade) has support for hooking your iDevice up to a computer to debug sites on the iDevice through desktop Safari. See: http://adrielservice.com/blog/?p=894 Also, Chrome (and probably other browser) allow you to emulate touch events in the desktop version.

Answer (score 5):

You can add a window level error handler

http://dev.opera.com/articles/view/better-error-handling-with-window-onerror/

and have that console log the line number. You'll be getting two console logs per error, but you will have more control over the output.

Answer (score 0):

You can try using regular Safari or Chrome and write it there first before using the iPad or alternatively there is the Weinre application that provides you a console like firebug / chrome developer tools.

Comment: the web application handles touch and gesture events, I cannot test them on desktop version of the browser

Comment: You can emulate touch events in chrome by clicking on the settings button in the debug console and checking: "emulate touch events". Not sure about gestures.