# Showing file and line of javascript syntax error in Safari

Tags: javascript, safari, stack-trace

For the following error:

```
SyntaxError: Unexpected token '='. Expected an opening '(' before a method's parameter list.
```

[image]

Safari is not showing a proper stacktrace with *file* and *line*.  Note there is no inline javascript code in the html: it is all in `.js` files. How can I get a better handle on where this error is occurring?

Comment: Ah fair enough: that's not a ST. But yea FF and Chrome do show File:Line for syntax errors. I will re-word the question

Comment: Maybe this helps. I havent read it in full but has some upvotes https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9120000/safari-for-ipad-not-reporting-line-numbers-on-javascript-errors     .... i know it says a mobile device, but 1st answer by M Marsh may be promising

Comment: @GetSet nice find!  trying it out

Comment: Its a good question, glad to help

Comment: @GetSet Pls make an answer.  btw the specific error above is not working for it: for some reason it does not get the file/line but most errors do

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Per [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12630405/332578) that links to [this post](https://dev.opera.com/articles/better-error-handling-with-window-onerror/)

override your `window.onerror` like so

```
window.onerror = function(message, url, linenumber) {
    alert('JavaScript error: ' + message + ' on line ' + linenumber + ' for ' + url);
}
```

If you're working on a production app you really should use babel, which will solve issues like this for you. If it's not solving these issues make sure to update your packages / npm etc etc.

To get a bit more technical this is because you (or one of your users) are using an outdated version of safari that officially supports only SOME of the latest and greatest javascript improvements. Upgrading Safari may also take care of this issue, depending on when you read this.

Cheers